# Complex .htaccess question

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Assuming I have the following file structure:

www.example.com/index.php (home page)
www.example.com/about.php
www.example.com/services.php
www.example.com/contact.php

How can I use mod_rewrite in an .htaccess file so when the browser points to:
www.example.com/about.php

the actual URL displayed will be:
www.example.com/about/

However, I do not want this to apply to index.php
In other words, I do not want to see:
www.example.com/index/

Thanks for any help as I am about to go bat s**t insane trying to figure this out....  :D

Comment: +1 for **complex**. Seriously.

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/$ $1.php [L]
```

edit: i guess this is better

Comment: I like it, but why the `([0-9]+)-` at the beginning of the match? Also, shouldn't the `RewriteCond` also have an anchor to avoid matching `/about/index.php`?